# Connecting different goal types to see correlations in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, conversions, universal-analytics, goal-tracking

I am looking for a way to connect asset download goals early in the buying cycle with signups at the end of the cycle.

My website has complex buying cycle that happens over the course of months, for which we have top, mid, and bottom of marketing funnel goals. The top of funnel goals include downloads of white papers and ebooks, whereas the middle and bottom of funnel are downloads of solution assets and sign ups for free trials, demos, etc.

I am hoping to find a way to see in Google Analytics see how many mid and bottom of funnel goals were tied to a user conversion on top of funnel resources.

Is there a way in Google Analytics to connect multiple goals to a user?